# Autostart Node.js app (Ghost Blog) on server restart

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, digital-ocean, ghost-blog

After my preparation and installation of Ghost, I'm stuck with setting my DO Ubuntu to auto-start itself on server restart. I was suggested to use forever, and I do use it, however as far as I can understand from the concept of it; forever is just to keep the process running once it's started, and it vanishes (needs to be manually started) on each restart.

I'm looking for a solid solution that will keep multiple nodejs apps alive, even when the server is restarted or completely crashed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For howtoinstallghost.com, allghostthemes.com, ghostforbeginners.com we use pm2 to keep Ghost running.  We have a write up on how to setup pm2 here:

http://www.allaboutghost.com/keep-ghost-running-with-pm2/

Comment: I've struggled with pm2 without much hope. Even the installation was problematic. Additionally, for some reason it fills up the ram of my droplet.

Comment: In the end, pm2 was my solution.

Answer (score 2):

DigitalOcean's one-click Ghost app use an Upstart script to have Ghost start on boot. It looks like:

```
description "Ghost: Just a blogging platform"

start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up IFACE=eth0)
stop on runlevel [!12345]

# If the process quits unexpectedly trigger a respawn
respawn

setuid ghost
setgid ghost
env NODE_ENV=production
chdir /var/www/ghost

exec /usr/local/bin/npm start --production

pre-stop exec /usr/local/bin/npm stop --production
```

and it is installed to `/etc/init/ghost.conf` This has the added benefit of allowing you manage it like any other service on your server with commands like `sudo service ghost restart`

Comment: Do services run like "forever" -- in terms of restarting themselves

Comment: Yes, it will respawn the process if it stops unexpectedly.

Answer (score 0):

You want to set it up as an init.d script so that you can start it or stop it as a service (and set it up to autostart using chkconfig).

Details are here:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBootupHowto

Note that's in addition to using things like Forever and Monit to restart on service crash and so on.

Comment: can you give me an example of this working with forever?

Comment: I have an example of using Forever here: http://www.howtoinstallghost.com/how-to-start-ghost-with-forever/

Comment: @howtoinstallghost I've seen that blog post, thank you for sharing it. However as far as I can understan it doens't help or the "restart" case, does it?

Comment: That's what Upstart is for, Zettam.